# Product of the first $n$ Fibonacci numbers is a perfect square

Tags: number-theory, fibonacci-numbers

Suppose that $F_{n+2}=F_n+F_{n+1}$ and $F_1=F_2=1$.

Can the number $P_n=F_1\cdots F_n$ be a perfect square if $n\ge 3$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is well known that the product $P_n=F_1\cdots F_n$ cannot be a perfect square for $n\ge 3$, see the
paper ["Diophantine equations with products of consecutive terms in Lucas sequences"](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X04001751?via%3Dihub) by F. Luca, T.N. Shorey. It determines all products of consecutive Fibonacci numbers which are perfect powers.

The argument is given also at [this MO-question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/38601/elementary-problem-with-fibonacci-numbers), relying on the fact that $F_n$ is a perfect square for $n\ge 3$ if and only if $n=12$.

Answer (score 1):

No,

If $F_n$ is the $n^{th}$ Fibonacci number (assuming we start, $\{1,1,2,3,5\cdots\}$ and not $\{1,2,3,5\cdots\}$) then

$n>2, F_n | F_m \iff n|m$

When p is prime, $F_p$ is co-prime with every Fibonacci number with index $< p$. (? I haven't proven this to myself yet, but it feels right.)

For any $n > 3,$ let $p$ be the greatest prime less than $n.$
$F_p$ is a factor of $P_n$ and $F_p^2$ is not.

Comment: It is not true that $F_p$ is prime when $p$ is prime. Rather, if $F_p$ is prime, then $p$ is prime. For example, $F_{19}=4181=37 \times 113$.

Comment: The crucial thing to note with @Aravind's example is that the only _Fibonacci_ numbers that divide $4181$ are $F_1$ and $F_{19}$.

Comment: You are right $37 | F_{19}$  Nonetheless, no Fibonacci number less than 19, is divisible by 37. I will think and revise.

Comment: It is true that $gcd(F_m,F_n)=F_{gcd(m,n)}$, so $F_p$ is co-prime with every Fibonacci number with index less than $p$. Also in addition you need that $F_p$ itself is not a square. It is known that the only square Fibonacci numbers are 1 and 144, so you can use that.

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely (and conjectured) that there is a number that is a perfect square and a Fibonacci Number $F_n$ as well, but remains unproven. If this is true, then $P_n$ is not a perfect square.

Comment: This is not true. $F_{12}=144$ is a square.